# How to wire a second light switch using 3 wire cable

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

There is an existing two gang box with 3 wire coming in. One switch is installed and working. The 3 wire cable goes to a junction box near the first light of a series in the basement. The light for the new switch I want to add is the last light in the series which are all connected by 2 wire cables How would you wire the second switch?

[image: light receptacle]

[image: 2 gang box]

[image: junction box]

Comment: Where does the black, red white cable go to?  The light box cable is only black and white, so is not the same cable.  Turn off the breaker for the other light switch and post a picture of the wires also.

Comment: @crip569 the 3 wire cable goes to the first light of a series in the basement which also has a wire supplying power. The light for the new switch I want to add is the last light in the series which are all connected by 2 wire cables.

Comment: We have some terminology issues and it gets confusing and the details matter **a lot**. So: How many cables go into the box with the existing switch? Where does each cable go? What color wires (and from which cable(s)) go to the switch? Which wire is hot when the switch is turned off?

Comment: in simple terms. As witch would have one permanent hot and one switched hot. No neutrals

Comment: With a picture of the first light box showing how the wires are connected we can give a good answer.  Turn off the breaker first.  Just to be sure everything is wired correctly.

Comment: @crip659 I erred, the 3 wire goes to a junction box near the first light in the series. See new pic of the junction box.